# oracle pivot query suggestion

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a simple table that has data like the following

```
     FiscalYear             Month               Value
      2013                   01                  10
      2013                   02                  15
```

....

```
      2014                   01                  15
      2014                   02                  20
```

using Oracle(11g) Pivot query is it possible to get something like this?

```
     Month   2013   2014
      01      10     15
      02      15     20
```

Comment: I know i can get the desired output using case when, but i am trying to understand the oracle pivot operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT month, value_2013, value_2014
FROM   (SELECT fiscalyear, month, value FROM your_table) 
PIVOT (SUM (value) AS value                                                         
       FOR (fiscal_year)                                                         
       IN ('2013', '2014'))
```

Comment: Thanks that worked..For some reason i was trying to pivot the month column instead of the value column..dumb!! Thanks!!